# Nullable column causes SlickException when trying to write null value

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In my Play + Slick 3.2.1 (using PlaySlick 3.0.0) project, I'm trying to have a nullable column `password_id` on a table `user`:

```scala
case class User(id: Long, name: String, passwordId: Option[Long]) extends Identity

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name", O.Unique)
  def passwordId = column[Option[Long]]("password_id", O.Unique)
  def password = foreignKey("password", passwordId, Passwords.passwords)(_.id)

  override def * = (id, name, passwordId) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

Table creation in evolutions script:

```sql
create table user (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password_id BIGINT UNIQUE,
  FOREIGN KEY(password_id) REFERENCES password(id)
);
```

Now, when I'm trying to insert a new user into that table as follows

```
def dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
dbConfig.db.run(users += User(0, "test", None))
```

I run into an exception:

```
slick.SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column <computed>
at slick.jdbc.SpecializedJdbcResultConverter$$anon$1.read(SpecializedJdbcResultConverters.scala:27)
at slick.jdbc.SpecializedJdbcResultConverter$$anon$1.read(SpecializedJdbcResultConverters.scala:24)
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:56)
at slick.relational.ProductResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:46)
at slick.relational.TypeMappingResultConverter.read(ResultConverter.scala:136)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcInvokerComponent$QueryInvokerImpl.extractValue(JdbcInvokerComponent.scala:36)
at slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker$$anon$1.extractValue(StatementInvoker.scala:67)
at slick.jdbc.PositionedResultIterator.fetchNext(PositionedResult.scala:176)
at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.update(ReadAheadIterator.scala:28)
at slick.util.ReadAheadIterator.hasNext(ReadAheadIterator.scala:34)
...
```

To me, this indicates that Slick still interprets `password_id` as  non-nullable.

Am I missing something in my config, or might this be a bug?

*(For what it's worth, I couldn't find any example/seed project for Slick 3.x using nullable columns at all.)*

---

### Update: Mystery solved

After further investigation it turns out I've been looking in the wrong place.

There was a different table with a property not declared as nullable (i.e. `Option[...]`) that unexpectedly was fed a null value. Because of the async nature of DB operations and the fact those two happened almost at the same time, I was wrongly led to above assumptions when debugging. To be fair, that error stack trace wasn't too helpful either.

*I'll just leave this question for posteriority, so people investating similar issues can learn from my mistakes.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your column shape from:

```
 override def * = (id, name, passwordId) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
```

to:

```
 override def * = (id, name, passwordId.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
```

Additionally, remove the option[Long] from the passwordId def to just Long?

Comment: I've tried that, but with the exact same result. I'm not sure, but I think Slick treats the two representations equally, as `.?` lifts a column to an Option.

Comment: How about setting a default value? O.Default(None) to the passwordId def?

Comment: Hmm, same result.